# How to script commands to run inside program

Tags: linux, bash, bluetooth, octave

Two questions with (hopefully) same solution. I want to automate the following:

$ octave

octave:1> 1+1

and

$ bluetoothctl

[bluetoothctl] connect "bluetooth MAC adress"

What I have tried so far is:

octave; 1+1

and

octave && 1+1

however this merely starts octave and once it is terminated with ctr+z the second command is run (as it should), I wonder if there is any way to send commands directly to be executed inside a program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Octave seems to understand input from STDIN:

```
echo 1+1|octave
ans =  2
```

As for bluetoothctl, can't test at the moment.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, worked for bluetoothctl as well!